# How can I call exported functions (dynamically in LLVM IR)?

Tags: c++, assembly, shared-libraries, interpreter, llvm-ir

I want to call the exported functions (functions from the shared libs - .dll, .so, end so on).
From what I’ve seen so far, it’s seemed, as I can’t, because IR have no stack (is it true, about the stack?).

With the C++, I can write something like this (for x86):

```
// args - an array of a tagged unions.
// out  - points to the place where we want to place the returned value of the func (if the func has one).
void callIt(void* func, Argument* args, size_t argc, void* out) {
  // This macro extracts values from the args array, and put them to the stack.
  // It's also change the ESP register according to the size of the extracted values.
  #define PUT_ARGS_INTO_STACK __asm { ... }

  // This macto calls the func,
  // and writing func's returned value to the out.
  #define CALL_WITH_RET __asm { ... }

  // This macro calls the func.
  #define CALL_WITHOUT_RET __asm { ... }

  if (size > 0)
    PUT_ARGS_INTO_STACK;

  if (out != nullptr)
    CALL_WITH_RET;
  else
    CALL_WITHOUT_RET;
}
```

And then we can use it like this:

```
void main() {
  // double pow(double, double);
  void* pow = importFunc("math.dll", "pow"); // Load DLL.

  Argument* args = makeArguments(2.0, 2.0); // makeArgument is a variadic tamplate.
  double* four;
  callIt(pow, args, 2, (void*)four); // Call the pow function.

  // This will be print 4.0.
  std::cout << *four << std::endl;
}
```

How can I write this code (callIt) in pure IR without another asm?

P.S. I’ve tried to look in the source-code of the Julia language (because language which I work is dynamic language as well as Julia), but It’s so hard for me to understand Julia’s sources.

Language that I use is dynamic, so a user may write, just in terminal, something like this:

```
> lang-interpreter
> pow :: double -> double -> double
> pow = importFunc("math.dll", "pow")
> pow(2.0, 2.0)
4.0
```

Comment: You are looking for something like the [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Comment: Not true about LLVM-IR not providing a stack, if you 'clang -S -emit-llvm youfile.c' you will see your main function creating stack space `alloca` to store the function pointer, etc.